# Package ‘stringr’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it BiocManager Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages

Tags: r, installation, package, bioconductor

Got the errors
`Error : package ‘stringr’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it` and B`iocManager Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages:`

and further down the road rstudio gave me

```
/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long answer to how to fix these errors but I assume necessary and also tips and tricks included (e.g. don't install R 4.0.2 right now (Jul 25, 2020)). It caused me a lot of pain because there were many more errors that I ran into on the way.
`Error : package ‘stringr’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it` and B`iocManager Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages:`

I removed .RData in my home folder (invisible, use `ls -la`) This fixed my problem for the installed before R 4.0.0 error, but did not fix my bioconductor problems. I assume it might work if you only had the re-install error.

After many attempts at trying to get my packages to load but only getting these errors, I opted to reinstall R. In R, I ran `.libpaths` and deleted all the files in each of the directories.  I then reinstalled R by downloading R from https://www.r-project.org/ and ran the general compile commands in the downloaded folder `./configure --enable-R-shlib --with-blas --with-lapack` `make` `sudo make install`. The --enable-R-shlib is needed for rstudio to be able to use R, but the others aren't.

On Jul 25, 2020 I tried to install from apt on ubuntu, but rstudio was not able to find libR.so (error of `/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so not found`). I tried to compile from source R 4.0.2 with the `./configure --enable-R-shlib` which should make the libR.so but this returned an error.

I assume this to be an underlying problem as running `./configure --enable-R-shlib` compile from source with R 4.0.0, I got the files and Rstudio opened up (please fix R 4.0.2 and subsequently apt).

I then ran the general

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.11")
```

to install biocmanager and it finally worked.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem when upgrading from R 3.6 to 4.0 in my Linux box.
I am also answering this because this question is one of the first results google gives when looking for this problem.
It turns out that, even by removing R (apt purge) there is a folder that remains in the system creating a lot of problems for the future installation.
I want to link the GREAT answer that was given here and saved me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219737/installing-ggplot2-for-r-3-6-on-ubuntu-18-04

In Linux systems you should look in:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
```

If the folder has a list of directories you should remove everything with:

```
sudo rm -Rf /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
```

Then reinstall R and all the libraries.